# property servicetoken cannot be empty

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

```
"certificatefordns":{
  "Type" : "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
  "Properties" : {
      "DomainName" : "*.test-elb.acb.com",
      "ValidationMethod" : "DNS"
},
 "CertificateDNSRecord":{
    "Type": "Custom::CertificateDNSRecord",
   "Properties": {
      "CertificateArn": {
        "Ref": "certificatefordns"
      },
      "DomainName": "*.test-elb.acb.com"
   }},
"DNS": {
            "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "HostedZoneId": "Z01724793QXGY7AZ",
                "RecordSets": [
                    {
                        "Name": {
                            "Ref": "AlternateDomainNames"
                        },
                        "Type": "A",
                        "AliasTarget": {
                            "HostedZoneId": "Z23TAZ6MNIO",
                            "DNSName": {
                                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                    "WebLoadBalancer",
                                    "DNSName"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${CertificateDNSRecord.Name}"
                    },
                    "Type": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${CertificateDNSRecord.Type}"
                    },
                    "TTL": "60",
                    "Weight": 1,
                    "SetIdentifier": "*.test-elb.acb.com",
                    "ResourceRecords": [
                        {
                            "Fn::Sub": "${CertificateDNSRecord.Value}"
                        }
                    ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Hi Team,
I want to create a new certificate for Load balancer and with the help of this json code I am able to create that certificate but after some time it will through an error that **property servicetoken cannot be empty** So As i searched I am confused that I need to create lambda function or what?
Or Is there any other way to decline this error.
Please guide me into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got the solution own my own. We just need to use this template that's it.

```
"certificatefordns":{
  "Type" : "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
  "Properties" : {
      "DomainName" : "*.test-elb.acb.com",
      "ValidationMethod" : "DNS",
      "DomainValidationOptions": [
                {
                    "DomainName": {
                      "Ref": "AlternateDomainNames"
                    },
                    "HostedZoneId": "Z01724793QXGL8FOZ"
                }]
    }
},
```

It will create a new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

**Custom resources** in CloudFormation require a [ServiceToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html):

- The service token that was given to the template developer by the service provider to access the service, such as an **Amazon SNS topic ARN** or **Lambda function ARN**. The service token must be from the same region in which you are creating the stack.

Your `Custom::CertificateDNSRecord` is missing it. Thus you have to provide it.

If the custom resource is for validating ACM certifications, you can check the new option, which should not require custom lambda function:

- [AWS Certificate Manager Extends Automation of Certificate Issuance Via CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/aws-certificate-manager-extends-automation-certificate-issuance-via-cloudformation/)

Comment: CertificateDNSRecord This is present in the json please check 
Also If I haven't create any SNS or Lumbda function So I need to create that for ServiceToken?

Comment: @shubhamkamboj Yes, you need to create the custom lambda and provide its arn as a service token.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not an accurate solution because then we need to write a code or lambda and then it will become complex.
I really appreciate if you have any solution so that we don't need to put this ServiceToken in our template or if you have any template for this then please let me know

Comment: @shubhamkamboj Sorry, I don't have any code for that. Using custom resource means that you have to develop your own custom code for it.